# Email Notification Powershell Getting 2 Emails

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script, to get an email notification when a file is saved in a certain folder. It works really well the first time anyone saves, but after that you get 2 emails anytime someone saves. Can you look at the code posted below and see what I did wrong exactly or why this might be happening?

```
$folder = "Folder Path"
$mailserver = "mail server"
$recipient = "Alerts@Email.com"

$fsw = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder -Property @{
   IncludeSubdirectories = $true
   EnableRaisingEvents=$true
}
$created = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fsw -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier CreatedEvent -Action {
   $item = Get-Item $eventArgs.FullPath
   $s = New-Object System.Security.SecureString
   $anon = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON", $s)
   If (($item -notlike '~') -And ([IO.Path]::GetExtension($item) -ne '.tmp')) {
            Send-MailMessage -To $recipient `
                -From "Email@Email.com" `
                -Subject “File Creation Event” `
                -Body "A file was created: $($eventArgs.FullPath)" `
                -SmtpServer $mailserver `
                -Credential $anon
}
}
```

Comment: The `FileSystemWatcher` is typically going to behave as it is configured.  Have you looked at all into the specifics of setting particular `Events`?  I suspect this has something to do with a file appearing, and then finishing being written to.

Comment: Take a look at the `Events` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#events and see if that helps you isolate specific behaviors to do the email, and eliminate any others that may not (such as `Created`, as I'm guessing).

Comment: [Created Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks): 
Common file system operations might raise more than one event. For example, when a file is moved from one directory to another, several OnChanged and some OnCreated and OnDeleted events might be raised. Moving a file is a complex operation that consists of multiple simple operations, therefore raising multiple events. Likewise, some applications (for example, antivirus software) might cause additional file system events that are detected by FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: I just want an email when a file is created. I don't need one for any other reason. Is there a better way to do it other than the way I have that might not give me two emails.